# How to do a USER NAME & PASSWORD protection in a web site before it is loading

Tags: php, javascript

How can we able to protect a site using USERNAME and PASSWORD after we entering the URL and the site is before loading

For ex: http://www.buildyourownbouquet.com/

I need exactly what it looks like...

Thanks in Advance

Fero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php has a mechanism for this. see example #2 on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) of the manual.

Or, as x2 pointed out, you could use htaccess. I assume you are using apache. Check [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html).

Answer (score 5):

It's called HTTP authentication. If you're using Apache, you can read about it [in the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an htaccess generator for you, simple enter the details, download htaccess and place it in the directory you want to protect:

http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/

Answer (score 2):

This is called a HTTP AUTH. And is described in this [tutorial](http://is.php.net/manual/bg/features.http-auth.php)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with htaccess file.

Comment: would you please explain how ?